# How can I select distinct records by a name?

Tags: sql-server

My table `Tags` has these records

```
Application   ID                                      TagName
/Blogs        A75FB4D9-B0A2-45B1-A58D-9CC4E7FC1482    TagA
/News         E1BDEF9D-4285-464F-88DC-00495B59D2AE    TagA
/News         997F1721-335B-477A-9943-B91F0C21DE74    TagB
/Blogs        BB1CEE87-AF8A-44D6-8A4B-EAB138BBEF10    TagB
```

I want to return only the first match of `TagA` and `TagB`, but the returning table must look exactly like the above (Application, ID, TagName), so I expect it to be:

```
/Blogs        A75FB4D9-B0A2-45B1-A58D-9CC4E7FC1482    TagA
/News         997F1721-335B-477A-9943-B91F0C21DE74    TagB
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How have you decided that your [Blogs,TagA] record > [News,TagA] ?  Database tables have no implicit ordering

Comment: Is there any Identity column on the table?

Comment: ID is set as ROWGUID. The primary key is `Application+ID`. The order doesn't matter.

Comment: In that case you will need to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### SQL Server 2005+

```
 SELECT Application, Id, TagName
 FROM
 (SELECT Application, Id, TagName,
  ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (partition by TagName order by TagName) rn
  FROM Table
 ) x 
 WHERE rn =1
```

Comment: This will only work for SQL 2005 and up, which is probably what he has.

Comment: You need to alias the inner select, replace `)` with `) r`

Comment: It returned one result with `/Blogs` and another with `/News`, all the other records where ignored. I want to get only distinct TagNames, so it is possible to return `/Blogs TagA`, `/Blogs TagB`, but not `/Blogs TagA`, `/Blogs TagA`.

Comment: @BrunoLM, added removed TagName from partition clause

Comment: Should be `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY Id)`

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick...

```
SELECT MIN(Application), MIN(ID), TagName FROM Table GROUP BY TagName
```

In this example you will get an id that is not predictable...

Comment: Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for min operator.

Comment: CAST(MIN(CAST(ID as nvarchar(100))) as uniqueidentifier) i hate this approach but it works

Comment: With Brian's fix it works. I wonder which is faster, this method or Michael's method?

Answer (score 0):

In the intesest of providing a non sql server specific answer

```
SELECT Application, Id, TagName
FROM Tags t
JOIN (
    SELECT Application, TagName, MAX(InsertOrder) LatestInsert
    FROM Tags
    GROUP BY Application, TagName
) l ON l.Application = t.Application AND l.TagName = t.TagName AND l.LatestInsert = t.InsertOrder
```

**This assumes the existance of a column which allows you to identify a "first" match** - note that if this is a timestamp its possible you may have two records with an identical insert time

Comment: Invalid column name 'InsertOrder'.

Comment: I've added emphasis, and I repeat my earlier question, in your example resultset how do you decide that [Blogs,TagA] > [News,TagA]